# Is numerical encoding necessary for the target variable in classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am using sklearn for text classification, all my features are numerical but my target variable labels are in text. I can understand the rationale behind encoding features to numerics but don't think this applies for the target variable?

Comment: You identify each textual label with an integer that represents the class it belongs to. If it is not possible than you are not doing classification

Comment: And what is the question? Scikit-learn handles the encoding of text targets on its own. Please explain in detail what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your target variable is in textual form, you can transform it into numeric form (or you can leave it alone, please see my note below) in order for any Scikit-learn algorithm to pick it in an OVA (One Versus All) scheme: your learning algorithm will try to guess each class as compared against the residual ones only when they will be transformed into numeric codes starting from 0 to (number of classes - 1).

For instance, in this [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html) from the Scikit-Learn documentation, you can figure out the class of your iris because there are three models that evaluate each possible class:

- class 0 versus classes 1 and 2
- class 1 versus classes 0 and 2
- class 2 versus classes 0 and 1

Naturally, classes 0, 1 and 2 are Setosa, Versicolor, and Virginica, but the algorithm needs them expressed as numeric codes, as you can verify by exploring the results of the example code:

```
list(iris.target_names)
['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']

np.unique(Y)
array([0, 1, 2])
```

> NOTE: it is true that Scikit-learn encodes by itself the target labels
>   if they are strings. On Scikit-learn's Github page for logistic
>   regression
>   (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py)
>   you can see at rows 1623 and 1624 where the code calls the label encoder
>   and it encodes labels automatically:
>
> ```
> # Encode for string labels
> label_encoder = LabelEncoder().fit(y)
> y = label_encoder.transform(y)
> ```

Comment: Thanks.

I tried using SVM, with and without numerical mapping, both seems to give the same result

Comment: sklearn handles the text targets on its own. No need to encode.

Comment: This was something that I didn't know of. I checked the code of the latest Scikit-learn package and I found out that it calls a LabelEncoder function for any target variable you pass it.

Comment: I did not check the code but I realised that the target variable encoding is necessary if you have installed using conda. But if you have installed using pip, we don't need encoding. I initially executed the code on pip installations and later installed condo for some reason. Then I realised this and had to change the code!!!

Comment: While `.fit`, `.transform`, and `.predict` support text targets, some functions don't ie. `metrics.roc_auc_score`. In that case, `LabelEncoder` is necessary:
    `enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(y_test)`
    `metrics.roc_auc_score(enc.transform(y_test),`
                      `enc.transform(xgb4.predict(X_test)))`

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is. Scikit-learn does automatic encoding for some of its training and prediction methods, as well as some scoring methods- but not for all. [Source code for skl's _encode method code here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/utils/_encode.py#L151). I don't know about other libraries but you they might not make this automatic encoding.

If you're working in a commercial environment, I think it would be best if you did encode your labels in the first place, so you don't have to redo your pipeline mid production phase.