# Should I cast target class as float or integer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

In `sklearn`, should I cast the `target class` as an `integer or float`? Will it make a difference?

I'm asking because I'm training a `Neural Network` and read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488279/neural-network-always-predicts-the-same-class) question that having a class casted as float may cause issues.

Then according to this question I think the answer is as `Integer`, but I would like to know if this is the case and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scikit-learn, it is indifferent to cast the target class to a float or int type (or even a string, see: [Is numerical encoding necessary for the target variable in classification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201315/is-numerical-encoding-necessary-for-the-target-variable-in-classification)), they are both allowed. You only have to notice that classification targets will be maintained in the same type as the input, thus if your input was a float type, you will get a float vector of predictions (see: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#type-casting).

In this example, you will directly verify how `KNeighborsClassifier` will produce the same class predictions (but with different data types, depending on the target class input type):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

data = load_iris()
(X_train, X_test, 
 y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(data.data,
                                     data.target,
                                     test_size=0.33,
                                     random_state=42)
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)

neigh.fit(X_train, y_train.astype(int))
int_preds = neigh.predict(X_test)

neigh.fit(X_train, y_train.astype(float))
float_preds = neigh.predict(X_test)

print(int_preds.dtype, float_preds.dtype)
print("Same classes:", (int_preds == float_preds).all())
```